# Last Element in List in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a list in Thymeleaf and I want to use th:with in a div to grab the last element in a list.  I've tried:

```
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(licence.registrations)}" 
            th:with="lastRegistation=${licence.registrations[__(#lists.size(licence.registrations) - 1)__]}">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><span th:text="${lastRegistration.name}"/></td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

However this gives me the error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "(#lists.size(licence.registrations) - 1)" (template: "admin/viewLicence.html" - line 103, col 10)
```

Does anyone know a way I can get the last item in a list with Thymeleaf?

Cheers,

Neil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using preprocessing, you need to surround the expression with `${...}`.  Like this:

```
    th:with="lastRegistration=${licence.registrations[__${#lists.size(licence.registrations) - 1}__]}"
```

That being said, there is no reason to use preprocessing in this case. (And I would remove the extra unused tags as well.)  This will work:

```
<tr th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(licence.registrations)}"
    th:with="lastRegistration=${licence.registrations[#lists.size(licence.registrations) - 1]}">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td th:text="${lastRegistration.name}" />
</tr>
```

You can also get fancy with collection selection & projection, but I'm not sure this is an appropriate use.  Still, it seems to work:

```
<tr th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(licence.registrations)}">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td th:text="${licence.registrations.![name].$[true]}" />
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help; I appreciate that the extra tag is there but it is there with a th:with because I then need to do a lot of stuff with that lastRegsitration reference.